# Making rigidbody magnitude constant in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I am trying to keep the magnitude of a rigidbody at a constant speed of 3.5. I don't want it lower or higher than that.

Here's what I did so far in FixedUpdate()

```
        if(rb.velocity.magnitude > 3.5f)
        {
            Debug.Log("ABOVE");
            rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, 3.5f);
        }
        if(rb.velocity.magnitude < 3.5f)
        {
            Debug.Log("BELOW");
            // Not sure if calculation below is correct
            rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * 3.5f;
        }
```

I know I implemented the first `if` statement correctly (clamping if it is over 3.5). I've searched around online and this is what some people suggested when it comes to clamping the magnitude if it exceeds the desired limit.

However, I'm not sure if I implemented the second `if` statement correctly (if the magnitude is lower than 3.5). I couldn't find any online posts/questions regarding this.

My question is: what is the correct way of setting the rigidbody's velocity if it goes lower than the desired speed? I have tested that clamping only works if the value exceeds the limit.

I want to keep the current direction, by the way. I just want to change/increase the speed. I'm not sure if using `normalized` is correct.

Appreciate any help. Still a newbie with physics/math programming.

Comment: wouldn't it be sufficient to just use your last line of code? `rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * 3.5f`. this just sets the magnitude of the velocity to 3.5 without changing its direction

Comment: @xyLe_ Yeah. I agree, that's much cleaner. (I didn't notice, actually, rookie mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.

You could also do what xyLe_ suggested in a comment and use only that:

```
if(rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude != 3.5f*3.5f)
    rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * 3.5f;
```

Calling a normalization is a bit time consuming (it needs a square root) but you won't notice any problem if you don't run thousands of instances of this object (and I suppose that the `ClampMagnitude` function needs a square root anyway and wouldn't be more efficient)

**Edit:** corrected the code regarding comment from yes

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I agree that xyLe's suggestion is cleaner. I've only got a single instance of this object so I guess I'm good.  I got a question though: is a normalized vector basically the direction of the vector? or am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: yes, it is the direction vector with a magnitude of 1

Comment: I see. Got it! Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: minor error in your code `rb.velocity` should really be `rb.velocity.magnitude`. also why not just set it each frame, its very likely that the velocity changes each frame anyway? also getting magnitude involves a squareroot, you could also check sqrMagnitude against the square of 3.5f (3.5f * 3.5f). but might be premature optimisation ...